# iOS - Integrating with Facebook.framework with other library having FB already

Tags: ios, facebook

I got a library from my client which has very old facebook src code integrated (which dont support single sign on). The library has additional functionality which I've to use in my application. 
Now to integrate latest Facebook.framework, I just removed .h files from the library that I have and added Facebook.framework to the XCode Bundle. But its throwing build error saying duplicate objects from Facebook.framework. If its .a file, I can set force_load in the settings, but this is a framework. How can I integrate Facebook.framework along with my library and resolve the build issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible.
Latest FB sharing is through a framework.
So, we can't even a rename the classes to use the latest framework.